# How can I have AutoImport.app automatically import my iPhone photos (like it did in the past)?

Tags: iphone, photos, image-capture

In the past I connected my iPhone to my Macbook, and I had AutoImport.app automatically import (and delete) all my photo's on my iPhone in a chosen folder.
Somehow this workflow has stopped, and I don't manage to get it working again. Instead, now I have to manually let Image Capture do it (don't like it, to much hassle).
Mac OSX 10.11.6, iPhone 7.

Comment: Checked on El Cap & Sierra, the old location listed in http://digitalphotobuzz.com/auto-import-your-photos-on-a-mac is no longer present `/Library/Image Capture/Support/Application/`

Comment: I still find it here: /System/Library/Image Capture/Support/Application isn't it the same location as it was?

Comment: ach, my bad - they used a horrible method of listing the path; yup still there.

Comment: On a side note - Image Capture is consistently erroring when importing from my camera cards since I upgraded to Sierra last week. It copies correctly but tells me it didn't. It then will not eject unless I drag it to the Trash in Finder. I'm going back to El Cap :/